# Existance of an element in Hilbert space with certain properties

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$F$ be a proper closed subspace of Hilbert space $H$, then to show that there exists some $x\in H$ s.t $||x||=1$ and $ dist(x,F)=1$ and $||x-y||=\sqrt{2}$ for every $y\in F$ with $||y||=1$ .

Any idea regarding how to approach this problem would be really beneficial.

Comment: Try this in $\mathbb R^2$ first

Comment: Then ? How to do it in arbitrary Hilbert space

Answer (score 0):

Suppose one such $x$ exists. Then because $$\|x-y\|=\sqrt 2\tag{1}$$
$$2=\|x-y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+\langle x, y\rangle=2+\langle x, y\rangle\tag{2}$$

Thus the condition is equivalent to $\langle x, y\rangle=0$.

This gives us a hint to consider any $x$ in the orthogonal complement $F^\perp$ of $F$, such that $\|x\|=1$. Clearly such an $x$ exists (since $F$ is not the entire space $H$).

By definition of $x$, we have that $dist(x, F)=1$ (easy to check). Furthermore, equation $(2)$, and thus equation $(1)$, are also verified for any $y\in F$ and $\|y\|=1$.